# Save states of multiple activities - Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, savestate

I have read many posts about how to save a state of an activity using `ViewModel` and `onSaveInstanceState()`, however, I couldn't find something that explains the possibility of saving multiple activities states to get back to them using an "Edit" button (to edit some application information). Is this doable? Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to consider having fewer activities, using fragments or composables to represent your screens.

Comment: @CommonsWare I appreciate your suggestion, but can you elaborate more? would it then work with many fragments? can we save several fragment states?

Comment: "but can you elaborate more?" -- not really. You seem to have a problem with multiple activities. Your question is unclear as to what that problem is,  as an "Edit" button is not strictly related to either a viewmodel or `onSaveInstanceState()`. However, modern Android app development, overall, is trending towards having fewer activities (see "single activity architecture" discussions). So, if your problem involves multiple activities, perhaps eliminating some of those activities may help.